# Is there an efficient way to compute the dot product of two 3D vectors from array index?

Tags: python, algorithm, dot-product

I am performing the following dot product of two 3D vectors:

```
import numpy as np

Nk = 8
Ns = 15
k_box = np.zeros(Nk**3)
R_box = np.zeros(Ns**3)
for k in range(Nk**3):
        Kx = int(k / (Nk*Nk))
        Ky = int(k / Nk) % Nk
        Kz = k % Nk
        for R in range(Ns**3):
            Rx = int(R / (Ns*Ns))
            Ry = int(R / Ns) % Ns
            Rz = R % Ns
            # This is the only place these variables are used!
            dot_product = Rx*Kx + Ry*Ky + Rz*Kz
            k_box[k], R_box[R] = perform_some_calculation(dot_product)
```

Is there a way to calculate the dot product without first computing the `x, y, z` components explicitly? Turning this into 6 loops would work, but would look gross. This seems like the kind of thing there would be a trick for.

I might also need to expand this to non-cubic volumes, so if there is a trick and it works for general box geometry, that would be ideal.

Comment: Your code makes no sense, since your inner loop just recalculates the value of `value` repeatedly--a different value each time, but only the last is stored anywhere. Is there an array or list or tuple or simple data container somewhere? Please explain your question more clearly.

Comment: Yeah I'll edit the code to make it more clear what I am doing. I was just trying to include only the relevant parts.

Comment: @ColinB: Any particular reason why you're converting your arithmetic results into integers (using `int()`)? will it be ok if I have them as float values?

Comment: @ColinB: Your question is: "Is there a way to calculate the dot product without first computing the x, y, z components explicitly? ". If that's really your question, it's out of my league, and I can only (diffidently) point you to the alternative definition of dot product (product of the magnitudes of the vectors and the cosine of the angle between them). But if your question is about reducing the number of visible loops, I can offer some solution. Pls clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Dot product should be done as follows

```
import numpy as np

R = np.array([Rx,Ry,Rz])
K = np.array([Kx,Ky,Kz])
value = np.dot(R,K)
```

Comment: This doesn't address my question.

Comment: what is the last line doing inside the for loop ?